# Can't get reverse proxy working

Tags: nginx, node.js

I'm trying to use nginx as a proxy for [this](https://github.com/rogeraleite/quickstart_ng2d3) nodejs app. What I've done so far is running the nodejs app with `npm --start` on `localhost:2791` with a `bs-config.json` which looks like this:

```
{
  "port": 2791,
  "server": {
      "baseDir": "src",
      "routes": {
          "/node_modules": "node_modules"
      }
   }
}
```

As for my nginx configuration it looks like this:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name demo.example.com;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    location /angular {
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header HOST $http_host;
            proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;

            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:2791;
            proxy_redirect off;
   }
}
```

When I access to `demo.example.com/angular` I get a:

```
[1] 17.06.10 18:35:51 304 GET /index.html
```

Which is great so far but this same page depends on other js files and when it tries to open them it can't find them so I get errors such as:

```
[error] 18#18: *1 open() "/etc/nginx/html/node_modules/dc/dc.css" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 81.64.208.179, server: demo.example.com, request: "GET /node_modules/dc/dc.css HTTP/1.1", host: "demo.example.com", referrer: "http://demo.example.com/angular/"
[error] 18#18: *3 open() "/etc/nginx/html/node_modules/core-js/client/shim.min.js" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 81.64.208.179, server: demo.example.com, request: "GET /node_modules/core-js/client/shim.min.js HTTP/1.1", host: "demo.example.com", referrer: "http://demo.example.com/angular/"
[error] 21#21: *4 open() "/etc/nginx/html/browser-sync/browser-sync-client.js" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 81.64.208.179, server: demo.example.com, request: "GET /browser-sync/browser-sync-client.js?v=2.18.8 HTTP/1.1", host: "demo.example.com", referrer: "http://demo.example.com/angular/"
```

**How can I tell nginx, instead of trying to find the files in `/etc/nginx/html` to pass the requests to the node app running on `127.0.0.1:2791`?** I tried to add `root /home/user/quickstart_ng2d3/src` in my config file but it didn't work as the sources/dependencies are spread into multiples folders of the project and are linked together with the help of the node configuration files. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Try `location /` instead of `location /angular`.

Comment: @RichardSmith Thanks it works!! But I actually would like to access to the project from demo.example.com/angular, how can I do that?

Comment: If you want to force index.html to load its resources from /angular. You could try changing the base tag at the top of the file.

Comment: @RichardSmith What do you mean by changing the base tag?

Comment: The 5th line in index.html

Comment: @RichardSmith Oh ok I see. But isn't there a way to do the same thing but without touching the source code and only the nginx configuration files instead?